# A question in ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am revising for the finals, these questions on book I just cannot answer. Hope somebody can help me. Thanks

> - Suppose that a belongs to a ring and $a^4=a^2$. Prove that $a^{2n}=a^2$for all $n\ge1$.
> - Suppose that there is an integer $n\gt1$ such that $x^n=x$ for all elements $x$ of some ring. If m is a positive integer and $a^m=0$ for some a, show that $a=0$.

Answer (score 4):

First:  Write $a^{2n} = a^{2n-2}a^2$ and use induction.

Second: If $m\leq n$, write $a = a^n = a^ma^{n-m}$.  If $m > n$, write $0 = a^m = a^na^{m-n} = a^{m-n+1}$ and use induction.